# OAuth client credentials (key + secret) needed in a desktop app even with valid token credentials

Tags: c#, wpf, oauth, dotnetopenauth

I was under the impression that once the authorization process is done, the access token and secret (token credentials) are all that is needed to use the target resource. According to this quote [[in some cases, the client credentials cannot be trusted and can only be used for informational purposes only, such as in desktop application clients](http://hueniverse.com/oauth/guide/terminology/)] this may not be the case. I am running into a problem that even after authorization consumer key and secret (client credentials) are still needed in order to access the resource. This does not seem right.

I have implemented `OAuth` in my desktop application looking up to the `DotNetOpenAuth` samples. I have basically used an unchanged `InMemoryTokenManager` and a `DesktopConsumer` and all works perfectly once authorized. When I restart the app and reuse the saved token credentials, the app fails to access the resource. If I used the saved token credentials + the client credentials, the resource is accessed alright. Is this by design? Sounds incorrect but I am no expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct.  Per the OAuth 1.0 spec, the client credentials are required every time you use the access token.  This protects a leaked access token from being exploited by another client.  This reasoning primarily assumes the client secret is in fact a secret, which as you point out cannot be assumed for a desktop app.  Nevertheless, you can have a "secret" that isn't a secret, and maintain it across launches of your app, just to keep everything ticking along.